# kernel panics on MacBook Pro (Early 2008), possibly SMC related

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, power-management

---

I am a proud owner of a MacBook Pro from Early 2008 (MacBookPro4,1), which is (apart from the problems) still running strong. Unfortunately I have been getting kernel panics for a while now. I am not 100% sure but I think it started after I let the battery drain completely one night with the MacBook being in Standby. The next morning it wouldn't turn on and I did not just have to reset the SMC but bypass it. After I started the MacBook that way I could restart normally. This was about two months ago and I think since then I get the kernel panics every now and then.

More Information:

- MacBook Pro (Early 2008)
- 6Gb RAM
- Mac OS X 10.11.6
- 2,4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo
- NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT 128MB

I also experienced the kernel panics in Safe Mode and during start-up and while I was trying to reinstall macOS. Right now I have the MacBook running while bypassing the SMC and I haven't had a panic yet.

The kernel panics appear randomly. I have the feeling that it happens more often when watching videos on youtube, but I can't say for sure. The battery is pretty much wasted and only holds for about 30 minutes. The MacBook usually turns off at 6-10%.

Then there is another problem, which might be related: When I use the MacBook <s>on battery and</s> with the internal keyboard and trackpad it sometimes hangs for a few seconds in which it first doesn't take any input, and then takes the input but doesn't show it until a short moment later. This has been a problem for a long time now.

Also I have recently noticed that I have been using the MacBook with a 60W power supply unit instead of the normal 85W unit. The original one was broken and I just grabbed another one that was laying around, not knowing that Apple MacBooks actually had different power supply units.

The Apple Hardware Test doesn't find any problems.

One more thing: My login screen shows a weird background. Kind of like the background is made for a screen with a lower resolution. This background is shown on the internal screen and on an external screen.

[image: weird login screen]

A look into the kernel panic reports shows that most of the are due to page faults with error code 0 (meaning that a page was requested, that doesn't exist).

I would put all the reports up, but that might be too much in this question? Here are the two last recent ones.

```
Sat Apr 22 17:27:51 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80021ce6fa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8002182e33, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000030, CR3: 0x00000000076a7000, CR4: 0x0000000000002660
RAX: 0x0000000000000030, RBX: 0xffffff800d358840, RCX: 0x0000000000000030, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff90d88ab4c0, RBP: 0xffffff90d88ab4f0, RSI: 0x000000004758c4a4, RDI: 0xffffff80087169b8
R8:  0xffffff8014ad3000, R9:  0x0000000000060000, R10: 0xffffff90d88ab840, R11: 0x000000330f4ec0d7
R12: 0x000000000009f376, R13: 0xffffff8007ec7000, R14: 0xffffff80087169b8, R15: 0xffffff7f80000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010207, RIP: 0xffffff8002182e33, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000030, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff90d88ab150 : 0xffffff80020dab52 
0xffffff90d88ab1d0 : 0xffffff80021ce6fa 
0xffffff90d88ab3b0 : 0xffffff80021ec563 
0xffffff90d88ab3d0 : 0xffffff8002182e33 
0xffffff90d88ab4f0 : 0xffffff8002185458 
0xffffff90d88ab510 : 0xffffff80021855d7 
0xffffff90d88ab560 : 0xffffff8002186cdb 
0xffffff90d88ab5b0 : 0xffffff800217b2eb 
0xffffff90d88ab880 : 0xffffff80022eefa9 
0xffffff90d88aba20 : 0xffffff80022e9b12 
0xffffff90d88abcb0 : 0xffffff800251163c 
0xffffff90d88abd40 : 0xffffff8002327138 
0xffffff90d88abdc0 : 0xffffff7f85bd39dd 
0xffffff90d88abe40 : 0xffffff7f8587c310 
0xffffff90d88abf20 : 0xffffff7f82f98173 
0xffffff90d88abfb0 : 0xffffff80021c9117 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked(417.4)[0FA751C4-806C-331B-9B87-435295111F6F]@0xffffff7f82f97000->0xffffff7f82fa9fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.DiskImages(417.4)[CDCF4D3F-89CC-3CDD-AB89-B6FFD304F26B]@0xffffff7f82f79000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[DC1AAB7C-F417-3238-BB3F-2A5B84D67B90]@0xffffff7f82928000
         com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore(417.4)[BAB5FE66-ED6B-3B29-B582-1353E46F3CD9]@0xffffff7f85bd2000->0xffffff7f85bd4fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked(417.4)[0FA751C4-806C-331B-9B87-435295111F6F]@0xffffff7f82f97000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.DiskImages(417.4)[CDCF4D3F-89CC-3CDD-AB89-B6FFD304F26B]@0xffffff7f82f79000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[DC1AAB7C-F417-3238-BB3F-2A5B84D67B90]@0xffffff7f82928000
         com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage(417.4)[91BBDB10-ED64-3492-B2B2-41004A99260F]@0xffffff7f8587b000->0xffffff7f85885fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked(417.4)[0FA751C4-806C-331B-9B87-435295111F6F]@0xffffff7f82f97000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.DiskImages(417.4)[CDCF4D3F-89CC-3CDD-AB89-B6FFD304F26B]@0xffffff7f82f79000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[DC1AAB7C-F417-3238-BB3F-2A5B84D67B90]@0xffffff7f82928000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: rp=file:///com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001f00000
System model name: MacBookPro4,1 (Mac-F42C89C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 219301425385
last loaded kext at 112617077326: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 90.3 (addr 0xffffff7f863e9000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.8
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.1.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.nke.webcontentfilter  5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.SparseDiskImage 417.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  417.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   417.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.HTTPBackingStore    417.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    417.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 417.4
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   700.36.24
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleYukon2 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementDriver 218.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.MojoKDP  2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.6f1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

And the last one:

```
Sun Apr 23 00:43:22 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80025cbe03): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800257ff43, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000030, CR3: 0x0000000138e1b000, CR4: 0x0000000000002660
RAX: 0x0000000000000030, RBX: 0xffffff8009d9e240, RCX: 0x0000000000000030, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff800c823b80, RBP: 0xffffff800c823bb0, RSI: 0x000000004758c4a4, RDI: 0xffffff80068bda30
R8:  0x0000000000000001, R9:  0xfffffffffffff000, R10: 0x000ffffffffff000, R11: 0xffffff8013145c90
R12: 0x0000000000025466, R13: 0xffffff80060ab000, R14: 0xffffff80068bda30, R15: 0xffffff7f80000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010207, RIP: 0xffffff800257ff43, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000030, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff800c823810 : 0xffffff80024d7b92 
0xffffff800c823890 : 0xffffff80025cbe03 
0xffffff800c823a70 : 0xffffff80025e9ba3 
0xffffff800c823a90 : 0xffffff800257ff43 
0xffffff800c823bb0 : 0xffffff8002582568 
0xffffff800c823bd0 : 0xffffff80025826e7 
0xffffff800c823c20 : 0xffffff80025666c3 
0xffffff800c823c90 : 0xffffff800256d4e3 
0xffffff800c823cd0 : 0xffffff800256d200 
0xffffff800c823d00 : 0xffffff800256508a 
0xffffff800c823d40 : 0xffffff800255e26e 
0xffffff800c823e70 : 0xffffff80025534dc 
0xffffff800c823ea0 : 0xffffff80024fbaf1 
0xffffff800c823ee0 : 0xffffff8002997e38 
0xffffff800c823f50 : 0xffffff8002997b7c 
0xffffff800c823f60 : 0xffffff8002a255d1 
0xffffff800c823fb0 : 0xffffff80025ea3a6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: syncdefaultsd

Mac OS version:
15G1421

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Fri Feb 17 10:21:18 PST 2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.4.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9B4679AF-7EE6-3BCE-9DD7-C30975A80BB3
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002300000
System model name: MacBookPro4,1 (Mac-F42C89C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 19399144413118
last loaded kext at 189146929650: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard    181 (addr 0xffffff7f84ae3000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 317251235506: com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f84da0000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.1.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.1.14
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4728
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   700.36.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleYukon2 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

### UPDATE 1 (24.04.17)

The freezing depends on the use of the internal keyboard and trackpad only. It happens independent on the power source. With less RAM now, it eventuelly freezes and doesn't come back. It still reacts to external devices and the power button works as well.

The MacBook doesn't boot with the battery removed. I have done several SMC resets. Without the battery I can only boot by bypassing the SMC.

I have not had a kernel panic since I removed one RAM module, but of course this could just be, because it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Have you tried [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257)?  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already ran the Apple Hardware Test and it didn't show any problems.

Comment: Have you tried changing out the memory?  Page faults are memory related.

Comment: I don't have any spare RAM, so I will try to use both of them separately. Btw, El Capitan is no fun with 2Gb of RAM… ;)

Comment: I know what you mean.  Perhaps you could get a cheap 4GB PC-5300 memory module on ebay - your model can go up to 6GB max.

Comment: Also, try disconnecting your external screen.  When doing diagnostics, you should try to minimize the number of variables.  So, if the symptoms stop and then start back when you re-attach peripherals, you know it has something to do with what you are adding on.

Comment: It all also happens without the external display. (Especially this weird looking login screen.)

Comment: At the risk of asking a _dumb_ question, I notice you're _bypassing_ the SMC but have you tried _resetting_ the SMC more than once? Also, while you haven't been using the correct Power Adapter, this won't be the cause of your problem, so you can discount that concern for now. In addition to following the good advice offered by @Allan I'd really be looking at replacing your battery as it's current state could be the cause of a few of this issues you mention, although you may not want to do that until you're confident the MBP is still ok. What happens if you try using it without the battery?

Comment: @Monomeeth I reset the SMC multiple times now. The MacBook doesn't boot without the battery, unless I bypass the SMC. 

I'm getting the feeling that I have 2 or 3 different problems:
1) kernel panics: possibly memory related, I'm still testing the two modules.
2) "input freezings" when using internal keyboard and trackpad: I added a more detailed description.
3) SMC or battery stuff: MacBook shuts down at more than 5%, doesn't boot without battery.

Comment: I've just posted an answer to start a process of elimination.  With some patience we can try various things and I'll keep updating the answer along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination so we're going to need to have some patience. :)

Usually this site is geared to answering one question per question, but you've got a number of issues which may or may not be related, so we'll see how we go.

Before proceeding let's **ensure your MBP is running isolated from other hardware** (no external displays, hard drives, etc).

**Keyboard/trackpad**

Let's start with your keyboard/trackpad issues. I suspect this may be due to your battery, so we need to test for that. Since you can't boot without your battery, I'd try the following:

1. Boot your Mac as per normal (with the battery inserted **and** your Mac connected to AC power)
2. Now put your Mac to sleep via the Apple menu
3. Once it's in sleep mode, close the lid
4. Remove the battery
5. Open the lid
6. Assuming your Mac is still on and you can use it, test your keyboard and trackpad

Now, if your keyboard and/or trackpad are fine then you know their issue(s) are related to the battery. If this is the case, it's a simple fix - you need to replace your battery (although you may not want to do that until you know what's causing your other issues).

**Kernel panics**

For now, if you can still use the MBP after Step 6 above, use your Mac (watch videos etc) to see if you can generate a kernel panic.

Let me know either way how you go.

Comment: The MacBook doesn't wake up after I remove the battery. The only way I can use it without the battery is by bypassing the SMC. Could this be because of the wrong power supply unit?

Comment: Yes, that could explain it. The 65 watt unit you're using would still charge a battery for your MBP, albeit slower than an 85 watt unit. However, if you're not able to boot at all on AC power only then the power it's delivering isn't enough (according to the SMC). Can you confirm the steps you're using to bypass the SMC?

Comment: Also, when you used AHT, did you opt for the extended test? If not, then do the following: (1) Run it again and ensure you tick the checkbox for extended testing, but before doing so ensure you have both memory chips installed. (2) If you get a memory error, then run the extended test again after removing one of the modules. (3) Regardless of the result, swap the modules and run it again. Make sure you keep a track of the results.

Comment: I now have a 85 watt unit and I can boot and use the MacBook without a battery. So that's good. I was running the extended test and didn't get an error. But I will run it again. As far as I understood it, memory test aren't very reliable, because it cannot be completely tested. So running it multiple times increases the chances of finding errors.